# What algorithm is used for set intersection?

Tags: r

What algorithm, internally, does R use for set intersection, i.e. `intersect(x,y)`? There does not seem to be any info in the help file. As far as I can tell, it is not based on sorting and then merging `x` and `y`, as presorting `x` and `y` does not speed it up.

Comment: if you type intersect , you can see the code; ```function (x, y) { y <- as.vector(y)
    unique(y[match(as.vector(x), y, 0L)])
} ```

Comment: **Use the source, Luke**   No, really, get the source files.  They are all available at CRAN.

Comment: @StupidWolf, thanks, that skipped my mind. It does answer my question partially. So, `intersect` is just a wrapper around `match`. Then the actual question is, what algorithm does `match` use?

Comment: It calls a c-code and it's a bit beyond me to be honest. https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/match.c . Maybe you can tell me what it does

Comment: @StupidWolf  I happened to peek at that source recently.  I think basically the caller converts everything to strings and then the c-code just does pattern matching on the characters.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Found some time today to go through the source code. It's hash table based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `intersect(x, y)` is

```r
function (x, y) 
{
    y <- as.vector(y)
    unique(y[match(as.vector(x), y, 0L)])
}
```

`unique` is a generic function, with `unique.default` calling internal C function `do_duplicated`, which in turn calls `any_duplicated` or `any_duplicated3`. `match` calls internal C function `do_match`, which in turn calls `match5`. The respective C functions, `any_duplicated`, `any_duplicated3`, and `match5` use hash tables, see https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/unique.c.

So, `intersect` uses hash tables for computing set intersections, albeit a hash table would be constructed twice, once for `match` and once again for `unique`.